# How do I get rid of the preview of offscreen points in a zoomed in Highcharts scatterplot?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, scatter-plot, angular-highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to show multiple series of data, a few scatterplot and a few line. When I select an area to zoom in on a scatter point, I see a bunch of extra points that are supposed to be out of range drawn on the axis of the chart. Is there a Highcharts setting or a way to override the native zoom functionality to remove those offscreen points?

```
"@angular/core": "11.2.14",
"highcharts": "^9.0.1",
"highcharts-angular": "^2.10.0",
```

Here's the chart zoomed out. It has multiple series, but its the scatterplot series I'm debugging.
[image: Normal Chart]

Selecting my zoom area
[image: Selecting]

Zoomed in. Note that the other scatter points in the series are supposed to be way outside of the selected range but are still drawn on the axis.
[image: Zoomed selection]

Here are rough HighCharts options I'm using (labels and ticks [etc] get tweaked once data loads so its not exact):

```js
export const BASE_CHART_SETTINGS: ChartSettings = {
  chart: {
    renderTo: '',
    animation: false,
    backgroundColor: ChartColors.GridBg,
    plotBorderWidth: DEFAULT_GRID_LINE_WIDTH,
    plotBorderColor: ChartColors.BorderLine,
    marginBottom: 34,
    inverted: true,
    zoomType: 'xy',
    resetZoomButton: {
      theme: {
        style: {
          opacity: 0,
          display: 'none',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  title: { text: null },
  legend: { enabled: false },

  credits: { enabled: false },
  exporting: { enabled: false },
  plotOptions: {
    spline: {
      enableMouseTracking: true,
      marker: {
        radius: 3,
        symbol: 'circle',
        enabled: true,
      },
    },
    series: {
      enableMouseTracking: true,
      stickyTracking: true,
      lineWidth: 1.25,
      states: {
        inactive: { opacity: 1 },
      },
      turboThreshold: 1,
    },
  },
  boost: {
    enabled: true,
    useGPUTranslations: true,
  },
  lang: {
    noData: 'No Data',
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false,
  },
};

export const DEFAULT_SCATTER_SERIES = {
  type: 'scatter',
  lineWidth: 0,
  color: ChartColors.AxisLabel,
  enableMouseTracking: false,
  marker: {
    radius: 3,
    symbol: 'circle',
  },
  states: {
    hover: { enabled: true },
  },
  boostThreshold: 1500,
};
```

EDIT: On further experimentation, it looks like it may be related to the scatterplots being **boosted**. If I disable boosting, the scatterplots do not show the offscreen point preview. For performance reasons, though, I need to keep the points boosted, so I'm still looking for a way to get rid of the extra points showing up

EDIT 2: The documentation for [boostThreshold](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.boostThreshold) also mentions setting [cropThreshold](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.cropThreshold) to change how many points are actually drawn in the plot area, but I haven't been able to get it to work (setting cropThreshold to 1 still shows all of the offscreen points)

Comment: It's looks like the [scatter.marker](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.scatter.marker) make this slidge rest of the points on the screen.

Comment: Looks like its a known bug with the boosted module that they're tracking: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=48512; https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13170